# Как сделать контрол такой же как редактор запросов в тфс?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Tfs группировка]

Как сделать вот такую группировку элементов в DataGrid WPF.
Задача: В точности повторить контрол на скрине ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [How to: Group, sort, and filter data in the DataGrid control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control)

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит. Нужны именно линии группировки как дерево слева.

Comment: Идите в какой-нибудь devexpress и telerik, это непростой контрол и его создание выходит за рамки формата SO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293739/datagrid-that-also-supports-a-tree-view

Comment: Мне кажется что ничего особо сложного нет, делается из DataGrid  кроме ручного рисования объединяющих скобок, а как это сделать, смотрите пример любого контрола где есть custom draw. На msdn полно статей на эту тему.

Comment: DataGrid я использую, непонятно как объединить ячейки чтобы в них отрисовывать

Comment: Как я понял это DataGridView из WinForms